# Gunicorn: Worker failed to boot

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I'm trying to setup my django app with Gunicorn, Supervisor and Nginx. 
Nginx works fine. 
When i check the status of Supervisor i have the following message: 
`FATAL Excited too quickly`

I think the problem comes from Gunicorn as i can't make it work on its own.

I also use virtualenv. So this is my project structure:

```
- home
  - justine
    - bin
    - include
    - my_project_name
      - app
      - my_project
        - settings.py
        - wsgi.py
      - manage.py
      - requirements.txt
    - logs
    - run
    - share
    - lib
    - locale
    - requirements.txt
    - pip-selfcheck.json
```

In /home/bin i have a file `gunicorn_start` :

```
NAME="justine_cv"
DIR=/home/justine/my_project_name/
USER=justine
GROUP=justine
WORKERS=3
BIND=unix:/home/justine/run/gunicorn.sock
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=/my_project.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=/my_project.wsgi
LOG_LEVEL=error

cd $DIR
source ../bin/activate

export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DIR:$PYTHONPATH

exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $WORKERS \
  --user=$USER \
  --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=$BIND \
  --log-level=$LOG_LEVEL \
  --log-file=-
```

Also i have a supervisor file as follows at `etc/supervisor/conf.d/`:

```
[program:program-name]
command=/home/justine/bin/gunicorn_start
user=justine
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/justine/logs/gunicorn-error.log
```

When i try to start Gunicorn at `home/justine/` and type `gunicorn my_project.wsgi:application` i get the following error message:

```
ImportError: No module named my_project.wsgi
[2019-04-27 21:20:14 +0000] [24448] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 24448)
[2019-04-27 21:20:14 +0000] [24444] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2019-04-27 21:20:14 +0000] [24444] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

BUT, when i cd into `my_project_name` and type the same command, gunicorn starts with success.

I think gunicorn can't find the right path when i'm at `home/justine/` but regarding the configuration files, i can't see where the problem comes from.

Also, in the `run` directory, there is no `gunicorn.sock` file.

I have tried all the stackoverflow answers to related questions but with no success.

If it helps, i'm following this tutorial: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/14/how-to-deploy-to-digital-ocean.html

Comment: Did you make gunicorn_start executable?

Comment: Yes i did. `chmod u+x bin/gunicorn_start`

Comment: your project settings target is wrong "DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=/my_project.wsgi" . fix it correctly I think you will loose first slash.

Comment: @ytsejam i have tried to remove first slash but it doesn't change anything